# X11 programming, some questions

Tags: x11

I would like to make a simple visualisation using X11. I don't want a fancy guy with buttons and stuff, I simply want to display an ordinary line chart in a window and that's it.

Since I have not that much experience in programming X11, I used this example code:

https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Window_creation/X11#Xlib

It compiles fine and works, but when the window it creates is closed, the error

```
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0.0"
      after 11 requests (9 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
```

appears in the terminal. So I wonder what the reason for this could be and how it could be fixed?

Comment: We're a knowledge base, not a help forum -- each question should be *exactly one question*, posed as a [mcve] with everything necessary for someone to reproduce the problem themselves and test proposed answers.

Answer (score 0):

Use The Source, Luke.

```
while (1) {
   XNextEvent(d, &e);
   if (e.type == Expose) {
      XFillRectangle(d, w, DefaultGC(d, s), 20, 20, 10, 10);
      XDrawString(d, w, DefaultGC(d, s), 10, 50, msg, strlen(msg));
   }
   if (e.type == KeyPress)
      break;
}

XCloseDisplay(d);
```

If you exit the loop by pressing a key, you call XCloseDisplay().  If you kill the window "from the outside" (say, with your mouse) that function is never called.  The process goes away abruptly, and X warns you about it.

On my system at least, kill(1) doesn't produce the warning, either.  I suspect there's some interaction with your window manager, something you'll deal with later in your xlib education.  :-)