# What api does xorg (and wayland) use to display something on the screen?

Tags: linux, xorg

How does xorg render something on the screen? I assume it doesn't use a graphics api like opengl. Is it possible to use an api like that and draw graphics without xorg running in a program?

Comment: Of course X11 has a graphics api.  Here's a simple example: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53418710/1216776

Comment: Xlib talks to the xorg server, so it is the server that is actually drawing to the screen isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays they will normally use the [Direct Rendering Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_Rendering_Manager) subsystem of the kernel, which is accessibly via the `/dev/dri/*` device nodes and special files in the sysfs filesystem at `/sys`.

The server may draw via these interfaces to the screen for the client (e.g. in the case of basic X11), but the kernel API also allows the server to designate screen buffers for clients to draw to directly (hence the name), which is how wayland normally works, as well as X11's direct rendering extension.

---

Alternatively there is the older [framebuffer](https://docs.kernel.org/fb/framebuffer.html) subsystem of the kernel which can be accessed similarly via device nodes `/dev/fb*`, but that doesn't allow for hardware accelerated rendering.

Before DRM, X servers also used to access IO ports and memory-mapped IO for graphics cards directly and implemented the device driver to use the graphics cards in user-space itself.

---

You can use the DRM or framebuffer interfaces directly. Client-side libraries which are normally used with X11 or wayland, may have backends for either implemented as well. From memory I think at least SDL2 and GTK+ support both. But of course you will not really be able to use multiple windows with such a setup (except if you implement the window manager yourself).

Comment: So the kernel is handling the communication with the gpu/monitor and not xorg

Comment: @eser Nowadays yes, but in earlier days the X server would communicate with devices directly. Also, when using accelerated rendering via the DRM interface e.g. using OpenGL/Vulkan APIs, you still need these APIs translated to GPU-specific instructions. That's typically handled by the mesa3d library client-side in userspace.

Comment: Why is different drivers for xorg and wayland needed if the kernel provides a standard interface for this?

Comment: @eser What drivers do you mean? The video drivers for X are to provide hardware acceleration and GPU-specific configuration. You don't need any GPU-specific userspace driver for wayland to get some output working and I don't think you need it for X either, but it is going to be limited in functionality.

Comment: @eser DRM doesn't abstract all of the GPU details away. It just offers a uniform interface to access GPUs without having to mess with IO ports and IO memory directly. And kernel mode setting (KMS) as part of it moves the responsible of managing the display modesetting from userspace to the kernel.