# How does wayland compositors/wlroots actually render to the screen?

Tags: linux, xorg, wayland

What api does it use? (if it uses one). Could I make a program that just renders directly to the screen without wayland or xorg? How does xorg draw to the screen and is it different from wayland compositors?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What api does xorg (and wayland) use to display something on the screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74115722/what-api-does-xorg-and-wayland-use-to-display-something-on-the-screen)